# Drop rows from a slice of Multi-Index DataFrame based on boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

**EDIT:** Upon request I provide an example that is closer to the real data I am working with.

So I have a table `data` that looks something like

```
            value0    value1    value2
run step                              
0   0      0.12573 -0.132105  0.640423
    1       0.1049 -0.535669  0.361595
    2        1.304  0.947081 -0.703735
    3    -1.265421 -0.623274  0.041326
    4    -2.325031 -0.218792 -1.245911
    5    -0.732267 -0.544259   -0.3163
1   0     0.411631  1.042513 -0.128535
    1     1.366463 -0.665195   0.35151
    2      0.90347  0.094012 -0.743499
    3    -0.921725 -0.457726  0.220195
    4    -1.009618 -0.209176 -0.159225
    5     0.540846  0.214659  0.355373
```

(think: collection of time series) and a second table `valid_range`

```
    start   stop
run         
0   1   3
1   2   5
```

For each `run` I want to drop all rows that do not satisfy `start≤step≤stop`.

I tried the following (table generating code at the end)

```py
for idx in valid_range.index:
    slc = data.loc[idx]
    start, stop = valid_range.loc[idx]
    cond = (start <= slc.index) & (slc.index <= stop)
    data.loc[idx] = data.loc[idx][cond]
```

However, this results in:

```
         value0 value1 value2
run step                     
0   0       NaN    NaN    NaN
    1       NaN    NaN    NaN
    2       NaN    NaN    NaN
    3       NaN    NaN    NaN
    4       NaN    NaN    NaN
    5       NaN    NaN    NaN
1   0       NaN    NaN    NaN
    1       NaN    NaN    NaN
    2       NaN    NaN    NaN
    3       NaN    NaN    NaN
    4       NaN    NaN    NaN
    5       NaN    NaN    NaN
```

I also tried `data.loc[idx].drop(slc[cond].index, inplace=True)` but it didn't have any effect...

---

Generating code for table

```py
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame, MultiIndex, Index
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

valid_range = DataFrame({"start": [1, 2], "stop":[3, 5]}, index=Index(range(2), name="run"))
midx = MultiIndex(levels=[[],[]], codes=[[],[]], names=["run", "step"])
data = DataFrame(columns=[f"value{k}" for k in range(3)], index=midx)

for run in range(2):
    for step in range(6):
        data.loc[(run, step), :] = rng.normal(size=(3))
)
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Don't you want just `df[df['small'] > 1]`

Comment: @HarryPlotter This is just dummy data and a dummy condition. My real data and condition is more complicated.

Comment: Then you should clarify that in the description. Provide a more complex and insightful example that demonstrates the complexity of the filtering.  Because the proper ways depends on it. Why do you need to apply it to each animal group separately? Does the condition depend on specific values of each group? Do you want to do something completely different based on the group?

Comment: @HarryPlotter I updated the question with something that is very close to my acutal data

Comment: @HarryPlotter The reason I am often hesitant to do this is because imo, by keeping things as general as possible it leads to more generic code that applies to more people instead of specialized case-specific solutions.

Comment: Much clear now! I understand that, but the problem is that by not providing all the details and your ultimate goal, you give the wrong impression of the problem, and run into something called [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  People either tend to give up on helping because there is not enough information or tend to develop a much complex solution than should be because the real problem is simpler than they thought. Or you end being unsatisfied with the solutions because they can't be extrapolated to your specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, merge `data` and `valid range` based on 'run', using the `merge` method

```
>>> data

            value0     value1    value2
run step                               
0   0      0.12573  -0.132105  0.640423
    1       0.1049  -0.535669  0.361595
    2        1.304   0.947081 -0.703735
    3     -1.26542  -0.623274  0.041326
    4     -2.32503  -0.218792  -1.24591
    5    -0.732267  -0.544259   -0.3163
1   0     0.411631    1.04251 -0.128535
    1      1.36646  -0.665195   0.35151
    2      0.90347  0.0940123 -0.743499
    3    -0.921725  -0.457726  0.220195
    4     -1.00962  -0.209176 -0.159225
    5     0.540846   0.214659  0.355373


>>> valid_range

     start  stop
run             
0        1     3
1        2     5

>>> merged = data.reset_index().merge(valid_range, how='left', on='run')
>>> merged 

    run  step    value0     value1    value2  start  stop
0     0     0   0.12573  -0.132105  0.640423      1     3
1     0     1    0.1049  -0.535669  0.361595      1     3
2     0     2     1.304   0.947081 -0.703735      1     3
3     0     3  -1.26542  -0.623274  0.041326      1     3
4     0     4  -2.32503  -0.218792  -1.24591      1     3
5     0     5 -0.732267  -0.544259   -0.3163      1     3
6     1     0  0.411631    1.04251 -0.128535      2     5
7     1     1   1.36646  -0.665195   0.35151      2     5
8     1     2   0.90347  0.0940123 -0.743499      2     5
9     1     3 -0.921725  -0.457726  0.220195      2     5
10    1     4  -1.00962  -0.209176 -0.159225      2     5
11    1     5  0.540846   0.214659  0.355373      2     5
```

Then select the rows which satisfy the condition using `eval`. Use the boolean array to mask `data`

```
>>> cond = merged.eval('start < step < stop').to_numpy()
>>> data[cond]

            value0    value1    value2
run step                              
0   2        1.304  0.947081 -0.703735
1   3    -0.921725 -0.457726  0.220195
    4     -1.00962 -0.209176 -0.159225
```

Or if you want, here is a similar approach using `query`

```
res = (
    data.reset_index()
        .merge(valid_range, on='run', how='left')
        .query('start < step < stop')
        .drop(columns=['start','stop'])
        .set_index(['run', 'step'])
)
```

Comment: Thanks that works like a charm. Probably going to use a slight variation: Probably going to use a slight variation

`merged = data[[]].join(valid_range, on="run")` 

`step = merged.index.get_level_values("step")`

`cond = (merged["start"] <= step) & (step <= merged["stop"])`

`data[cond]`

Answer (score 0):

I would go on groupby like this:

```
(df.groupby(level=0)
   .apply(lambda x: x[x['small']>1])
   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)    # remove duplicate index
)
```

which gives:

```
                           big  small
animal animal attribute              
cow    cow    speed       30.0   20.0
              weight     250.0  150.0
falcon falcon speed      320.0  250.0
lama   lama   speed       45.0   30.0
              weight     200.0  100.0
```

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I am not sure if and how I can apply this. This solution leaves no room for more complicated conditionals (e.g. needing a few lines of code to set up the condition). As suggested by @HarryPlotter, I provided a more complex example that is close to my real-world data.